# Selenium code works fine on localhost but unable to catch the StaleElementReferenceException on Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jenkins, testing

Code:

```
try {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/table[@class='v-table-table']/descendant::tr/td[1])").click();
} catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
   // some code
}
```

This code works fine on local the exception is handled by the catch block and my code continue to execute, but when I run the same code on Jenkins catch block is unable to catch the exception.

```
Found Element By : By.xpath: //div/table[@class='v-table-table']/descendant::tr/td[1]
```

Logs :

```
Exception occured: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of <td class="v-table-cell-content"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'seliius26226', ip: 'a.b.c.d', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 78.9.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20210315154203, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 10789, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofileca5iLw, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: fefe7087-15e4-4b59-b908-55837803641b


Exception occured: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory


Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'seliius26226', ip: 'a.b.c.d', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
```

Comment: try with:  catch (Exception e)
 {
   if (e.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException"))...

Comment: This is not working I am getting the same error

Comment: you may just want to upgrade Selenium from 3.14 to 3.141.

Comment: if version is the issue then it should not run on local as well

Comment: @pcalkins please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/70260972/17543864

Comment: I just noticed you've got "EventFiringWebDriver" here.  You might want to use webdriverlistener instead... that might be throwing one or both of these errors.  Usually the IO error is because of a file upload where remote file configuration hasn't been set.  (There's a special way to do that for remote drivers...)  Kind of guessing here, but if you look at the first exception it doesn't match the code you posted.

Comment: You should also be using explicit webdriverwaits.  It'll help your code become more reliable whether it's remote or not.  Any time javascript is used to update the DOM webdriverwaits should be used.  Selenium automatically waits on a page load, but not when JS updates the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your ***java.version: '1.8.0_151'*** is too old and ancient.

Update *JDK* to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8) and execute your test.

---

### Update

The error error stacktrace also mentions about:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure)  56810K->10231K(139776K), 0.0097259 secs]
```

[GC (Allocation Failure)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html) is the effect of GC cycle to kick in.

***Allocation Failure*** means that no more space left to allocate object. Older JVM were not printing GC cause for minor GC cycles. *Allocation Failure* is almost only possible cause for minor GC. Another reason for minor GC to kick could be CMS remark phase (if `+XX:+ScavengeBeforeRemark` is enabled).

Comment: The same JDK is installed on my local machine but it is working there

Comment: @TARUNYADAV Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried this solution and I am not getting GC allocation failure, but the exception is still not catched

Comment: @TARUNYADAV Possibly _exception_ not happening when you are trying to catch...

Comment: please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/70260972/17543864